# conforming audio

Tags: post-production

Just getting myself ready to conform audio to some picture changes which 
I haven’t done before in Protools.
Is there any advantage in starting at the end to make the first change and working back to the start?
Would the editors notes lose their time location if I make the first edit towards the start etc..

Answer (score 3):

construct the new edit at a different location on the timeline to avoid confusion. If the picture start at 1 hour, do it at 4 hours for example. also means if something goes wrong you have the old layout available. If your changes are listed as 'add x frames here', 'cut x frames there' etc, then you will have to translate that into a series of cut and pastes - shouldnt be too hard if you take care.
Marc Specter

Answer (score 0):

+1 Marc. Definitely construct the new edit in a different location.

Region groups are your true friend in this process as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the original video file and the new video file running in frame mode and I can see when the frames visually go out of sync. I was wondering would it be helpful to cut the old video file with my grouped regions on the OMF or just leave the old video file unedited.
If the editor says cut x frames at a certain point will I have no reference on the old video to know where he is talking about?